# Performance of using a matrix as vector index

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

In my code I have a slow part of which the idea can be summarized in the following short example:

```
A = randi(10,5); %Random 5×5 matrix containing integers ranging from 0 to 10
B = rand(10,1);  %Random 10×1 vector containing values ranging from 0 to 1
C = B(A);        %New 5×5 matrix consisting of elements from B, indexed using A
```

In my case, the matrix A is sized 1000×1000, B is a 500×1 vector and C is also 1000×1000. Given that this 3rd line is in a for loop, where A is constant and B is updated every iteration, how can I further improve speed performance? According to the profile viewer 75% of code execution is at this single line. As expected, using a for loop for this operation is much slower (10x for a 1000×1000 matrix):

```
AA = A(:);          %Convert matrix to vector
for k=1:length(AA)  %Loop through this vector and use it as index
    D(k) = B(AA(k));
end
E = reshape(D,5,5); %Reshape vector to matrix of 5x5
```

Any ideas to optimize this?

Edit: Script used to measure performance:

```
N = 1500;
A = randi(500,N);
AA = A(:);
D = zeros(N,N);

B = rand(500,1);
f1 = @() VectorIndex(A,B);
timeit(f1,1)

f2 = @() LoopIndex(AA,B,N);
timeit(f2,1)

function C = VectorIndex(A,B)
    C = B(A);
end
function D = LoopIndex(AA,B,N)
    D = zeros(N,N);
    for k=1:length(AA)
        D(k) = B(AA(k));
    end
    D = reshape(D,N,N);
end
```

Comment: Preallocate `D`.

Comment: If you intend on modifying `E` after the loop then you're going to be better off reshaping `D` in place rather than creating `E`. `E` will remain a reference to `D` until one of them is modified, at which point it will be duplicated in memory which incurs IO time and additional memory usage.

Comment: Right, I could (should) have preallocated D. But note that the second code snippet would then still be much slower than the first method (snippet), and even the first method is too slow

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I don't find it "much" slower with R2017b. If the vectorized operation is "too slow" then you need to provide more details of your problem.

Comment: Indexing seems to be the big bottleneck in all MATLAB code... :) You're saying that this is too slow. How fast do you expect that this can be done?

Comment: Also: try putting this inside your loop: `D(k) = B(randi(10));` That is one less indexing operation you need to do. And, as suggested by excaza, do preallocate.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Cris perhaps you're right and this simply cannot be done faster. @excaza I have added some code to measure performance. For larger values of N the loop-method seems even to be faster (Matlab 2017b), which is not what I expected. Anyway, I found a way such that I do not need to construct the matrix C every iteration, which makes a huge difference. Thank you once more!